# Insert lookup formula using macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to insert an `If` formula to a cell (C2) using the macro code below. I keep getting the error

> Application undefined

Statement:

```
Worksheets("Dup Warnings").Range("C2").Formula = _
    "=IF(A2="","",IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"")=""New"",Sheet1!$G$2,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"")=""Review"",sheet1!$G$3,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"")=""New"",Sheet1!$G$2,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"")=""Review"",Sheet1!$G$3,"")))))"
```

Is there anything wrong with the formula?

Comment: One long single line

Comment: I fixed the case but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

You doubled up all of the quotes around the text string literals but not for the zero-length strings used as iferror defaults.

Instead of doubling up `""` into `""""` for zero-length strings, you can opt for TEXT(,)` which produces the same result and may be less confusing to the eye.

```
Worksheets("Dup Warnings").Range("C2").Formula = _
  "=IF(A2=text(,), text(,), IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, 'Appt Type Mapping'!A:J, 2, FALSE), text(,)) = ""New"", Sheet1!$G$2, IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE), text(,))=""Review"", sheet1!$G$3, IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE), text(,))=""New"", Sheet1!$G$2, IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE), text(,))=""Review"",Sheet1!$G$3, text(,))))))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your empty double quotes in the formula need to be doubled:

```
Worksheets("Dup Warnings").Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(A2="""","""",IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"""")=""New"",Sheet1!$G$2,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"""")=""Review"",sheet1!$G$3,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"""")=""New"",Sheet1!$G$2,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Appt Type Mapping'!A:J,2,FALSE),"""")=""Review"",Sheet1!$G$3,"""")))))"
```